# What steps should I take for safety when buying a used computer?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I bought a used Lenovo laptop from eBay and want to take steps to make sure it's safe to use. I ran the Windows 10 reset program (Start > Settings > Update & security > Recovery), which I think brings it to factory settings. Is there anything else I should do before using the computer with potentially sensitive information? I prefer not to replace the SSD.

Comment: Is there a Lenovo recovery partition on the drive?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to flash your motherboard ROM - I probably wouldn't bother though.

There is not much else you can do. The computer is almost certainly OK, however if the seller was malicious, extremely smart and well funded they could have added a hardware or firmware back door.Other then government agencies working in conjunction with chip manufacturers (almost all Intel CPUs built after 2008 are known to have government back doors for example - ie Intel Management Engine - your system is as safe as can be expected) and no less safe then a new computer bought off an an unknown vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If you completely reinstall Windows (factory reset) and use it, then very quickly the SSD will use and overwrite data so that it will become unusable except to you. It should be fine for you to use.